# Relative import errors - no known parent package

Tags: python, import

I have tried to fix this error in multiple ways but i cant seem to fix it please help :( (i have read other similar posts but nothing is helping i think I really have tried everything), i have the exact same on another project and its working but I don't understand why not in this.

I have the following structure:

```
    ODS
 .git
 can_bus
 database
 ods_main
 power_manager
    __pycache__
    testing
       __init__.py
       key_state.py
       power_manager_handler.py
       service_1.py
    venv-power-manager
     __init__.py
     Dockerfile
     features.json
     mqtt_client.py
     mqtt_configuration.py
     mqtt_initializer_pub.py
     mqtt_initializer_sub.py
     mqtt_pub_handler.py
     mqtt_publisher.py
     mqtt_sub_handler.py
     mqtt_subscriber.py
 services
   .gitignore
   __init__.py
   README.md
   shutdown_signal.py
```

[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoX8E.png)

```
my __init__.py in the main file is like this:
rom .mqtt_client import MQTT_Client
from .mqtt_configuration import MQTT_Configuration
from .mqtt_subscriber import MQTT_Subscriber
from .mqtt_publisher import MQTT_Publisher
from .mqtt_initializer_sub import MQTT_Sub_Initializer
from .mqtt_initializer_pub import MQTT_Pub_Initializer
from .mqtt_sub_handler import MQTT_Sub_Handler
from .mqtt_pub_handler import MQTT_Pub_Handler
```

inside testing/ in power_manager_handler.py im trying to import the power_manager library but I am not able to do it I have it like this as of now:

```
from power_manager import MQTT_Sub_Initializer, MQTT_Pub_Initializer, MQTT_Configuration
```

its not working with .power_manager either. I have tried many other ways but i get this erros:

```
❯  python3 power_manager_handler.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "power_manager_handler.py", line 4, in <module>
    from power_manager import MQTT_Sub_Initializer, MQTT_Pub_Initializer, MQTT_Configuration
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'power_manager'

y3qucfm at ODS/power_management/testing on  going-back-mqtt-class [$⇡]  via v3.8.10 took 5m53s
❯  python3 power_manager_handler.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "power_manager_handler.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .power_manager import MQTT_Sub_Initializer, MQTT_Pub_Initializer, MQTT_Configuration
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```